# How can I get the pid of a process who will receive the packet which I get in netfilter LOCAL_IN hook?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, netfilter

I added function added to netfilter LOCAL_IN hook, I want to detect the userspace process' pid who the new connection belongs to, what should i do?

I can get sk by check tcp_hashinfo, but the f_owner->pid is always 0.

btw: in LOCAL_OUT hook, I can get pid by current pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, feel free to refute me.

On an incoming packet, if it is a TCP SYN (so not part of an active connection), it can be going to a socket which is held by multiple processes (eg. apache using multiple worker processes). It could be accepted by any of them, therefore it is not possible to predict in the netfilter code which PID will actually accept the packet.

Once a connection has been established, you can also fork a program and have the handle open by both processes at once, which means that the data could go to one process or the other, or even split down the middle if one of them only reads part of the packet.

Because of this, Netfilter has no real way of knowing which PID will actually receive the data in any given packet.

Hope this helps, and (mostly) hope I'm not misleading!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @Joel C's said. The `current` macro in LOCAL_IN will always be `NULL`. But for TCP connection, I think there may be a small trick you can use to detect which process receives the incoming packet.

Set up a `LOCAL_OUT` hook alongside with the `LOCAL_IN` hook. Maintain a global data structure inside the kernel. When the `LOCAL_IN` hook receives a packet, stores the packet IP, port, sequence number and packet length in the global data structure. Since you are using TCP, the receiver needs to send an ack, so there will definitely be an outgoing packet for the incoming one. In your `LOCAL_OUT` hook, you can use the ack number of the outgoing packet to search inside the global data structure. Then you will be able to associate the previous incoming packet with a process id.

Comment: Agreed.  Linux still has a way to go in catching up with macOS which already has this capability.